# How does ngram parser and boolean mode search work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to query records containing a certain keyword, but sometimes it returns nothing.

I'm using MySQL 8.0.27 with config like this

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=OFF
ft_min_word_len=1
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
ngram_token_size=1

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

prepare test data like this

```
drop table if exists fulltext_test;
create table fulltext_test
(
    PDGDID varchar(30)
);

create fulltext index PDGDID on fulltext_test (PDGDID) with parser ngram;

insert fulltext_test (PDGDID) values ('CP20230817003');
insert fulltext_test (PDGDID) values ('C20230817P003');
```

I want to query records containing a certain keyword, but this sql returns nothing

```
mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+CP' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+CP' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                                               0 |
| C20230817P003 |                                               0 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+CP2023' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+CP2023' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                                                   0 |
| C20230817P003 |                                                   0 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

the rest sqls returns what I expected.

```
mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+C' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+C' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                     0.000000001885928302414186 |
| C20230817P003 |                     0.000000001885928302414186 |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+P' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+P' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                     0.000000001885928302414186 |
| C20230817P003 |                     0.000000001885928302414186 |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+C +P' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+C +P' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                        0.000000003771856604828372 |
| C20230817P003 |                        0.000000003771856604828372 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+2023' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+2023' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                               0.18123812973499298 |
| C20230817P003 |                               0.18123812973499298 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select a.PDGDID, match(a.PDGDID) against ('+20230817003' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| PDGDID        | match(a.PDGDID) against ('+20230817003' in boolean mode) |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| CP20230817003 |                                       1.8123812675476074 |
| C20230817P003 |                                                        0 |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there something special between letters and numbers?

UPDATE 2024-01-31

I found that as long as I search for consecutive uppercase letters, I can't find results, but lowercase letters works well. e.g.

```
insert into fulltext_test (content) values ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
insert into fulltext_test (content) values ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
insert into fulltext_test (content) values ('cp20230817003');

-- works well
select a.content, match(a.content) against ('+abcd' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
select a.content, match(a.content) against ('+cp2' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
select a.content, match(a.content) against ('+cp2023' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;

-- reutrns nothing
select a.content, match(a.content) against ('+ABCD' in boolean mode) from fulltext_test a;
```

But if i change the column to `utf8mb4_general_ci`, all the SQLs have correct results, it's just not case sensitive anymore.

Comment: Fulltext search is more for searching for words in a longer text, not to provide an alternative to like operator. Your use case seem to be better aligned for like.

Comment: yes, you are right, but i'm just wondering how it works

Comment: Have some Japanese or Chinese text and you will see :)

Comment: Yes, i just found this problem seems only exists searching for consecutive uppercase letters